# css main drop down menu is blinking and not expanding

Tags: css, html

[CSS](http://jamesburnett.com/css.txt)

jamesburnett.com

When viewing the site mobile size screens, the main menu becomes a drop down menu. When you attempt to click on it, it blinks for a second or two but doesn't ever drop down and stay. I've tested on iOS and Android, as well as just using the google inspect element. It fails to drop down on there too. I'm not quite sure what's wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess the problem is with JS and not CSS. The height is being altered vigorously by JS.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have deeper problems with the way things have been set up in html and/or js. `#main-menu > ul.menu{display:none;}` for media widths below 767px. Whatever is toggling display on the menu when you click is possibly triggering more than once or maybe not setting/toggling the classes the way that it should. Double check your naming, you might not be setting `dt-menu-expand` class, which, although it's hard to tell, it looks like that's what you intended from your css.